# Can a custom class know the name of the object that called it?

Tags: java, class, object, instance

Is there anyway, when calling a method through an object (instance) for that method to know which instance (object) called it?

Here's an example (pseudo code) of what I mean:

**Pseudo code example**

```
public class CustomClass{


public void myMethod(){


    if (calling method is object1){

    //Do something here

    }

        else {

        //Do something else

        }


        }//End of method


}//End of class
```

And then in another class:

```
public SomeOtherClass{

CustomClass = object1;

public void someOtherMethod(){

object1 = new CustomClass();

object1.myMethod();    //This will call the 1st condition as the calling object is object1, if it were some other object name, it would call the 2nd condition.

    }//End of method

}//End of class
```

**Possible work-around**

The only way I've found to do this is to get the method to take another argument, say an 'int' and then check the value of that int and perform whichever part of the 'if else' statement relates to it (or 'switch' statement if definitely using an 'int' value) but that just seems a really messy way of doing it.

Comment: Why do you want this? What are you trying to achieve?

Comment: Variable "names" really have no meaning. Note that several variables with different names can all reference the same object. It's object *references* that matter. I also agree with @Heuster, that your motivation behind this request will likely affect what might ultimately be the best answer.

Comment: @Heuster, it's for a collision detection routine, where I have 1 platform made of 3 tiles, a left, a middle and a right tile, the collision response will be different depending on which tile the character hits, thus I need the collision detection routine to know which type of platform tile it is processing.  I am creating 3 different objects (CDLeft, CDMiddle and CDRight and calling them all from my logic routine, but it doesn't know how to differentiate.)

Comment: Then perhaps it should be the Game object, the one that holds the tiles and runs the game, that identifies what tiles have collided, and then calls a collision method on both tiles, passing in to these methods what type of tile has collided with it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

What you need is the [Strategy Pattern](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Strategy_pattern)

```
public abstract class CustomClass {
    public abstract void MyMethod();
}

public class Impl1 extends CustomClass {
    @Override
    public void MyMethod() {
        // Do something
    }
}

public class Impl2 extends CustomClass {
    @Override
    public void MyMethod() {
        // Do something else
    }
}
```

Use it this way

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    CustomClass myObject = new Impl1();
    // or CustomClass myObject = new Impl2();
}
```

---

As your comment says what you really need is perhaps the [Template method Pattern](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Template_pattern)

```
public abstract class CustomClass {
    public void myMethod(){ // this is the template method
        // The common things
        theDifferentThings();
    }

    public abstract void theDifferentThings();
}

public class Impl1 extends CustomClass {
    @Override
    public void theDifferentThings() {
        // Do something
    }
}

public class Impl2 extends CustomClass {

    @Override
    public void theDifferentThings() {
        // Do something else
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks @Mohayemin, this is an interesting method, the only problem I can see is that the method inside my custom class is pretty big, I think with this way of doing things I would have to have 3 separate methods which are essentially the same, with just a few lines of code that are different.  Please correct me if I a am wrong on this?

Comment: @Zippy: any code that is common can be part of the super class's implementation, code that can be called by the child classes in method overrides if need be.

Comment: Well, if that is the case, you need another design pattern close to strategy, called Template Pattern, wait for a while so that i can edit the code that way.

Answer (score 0):

You can define a new attribute inside `CustomClass` which will store the identifier of the instance. If there will be only a few instances of `CustomClass` then you can use an enum type.

Replace:

```
object1 = new CustomClass();
```

with:

```
object1 = new CustomClass(1);
```

Add a new constructor and an attribute to CustomClass:

```
private int id;
public CustomClass(int id) {
    this.id = id;
}
```

Then you can replace:

```
if (calling method is object1){
```

with:

```
if (id == 1){
```

However, please keep in mind that this is a bad design.
You should not have if conditions differing logic depending on the instance which called this method. You should should use polymorphism for such purpose.

Answer (score 0):

You can know the name of current *class* by calling `getClass().getName()`. However you cannot know the name of object, moreover this does not have any meaning:

```
MyClass myObject1 = new MyClass();
MyClass myObject2 = myObject1;

myObject1.foo();
myObject2.foo();
```

Do you wutant `foo()` to know that it was invoked using `myObject1` or `myObject1`? But both references refer to the same object!

OK, there are extremely complicated ways to know this. You can use byte code engineering using one of popular libraries like javassist, ASM, CGLib and inject missing information about the "object name" into byte code and then read this information. But IMHO this is not what you need.